# Python UDP connect multiple servers

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm searching for the best way to connect my app to multiple servers. For example, I need to send one message to IP 192.168.1.3 and then another message to IP 192.168.1.4.

I'm using mySocket.sendto(data, (IP,port)) but it is slow for me.

Exists another way to do this more efficiently?

Pseudo-code:

```
mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.settimeout(1)
self.mySocket.bind((MY_IP, PORT))
```

Then I use a function to send:

```
mySocket.sendto(data_to_send, (IP_1, PORT))
data_rcv1, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
sleep(0.1)
mySocket.sendto(data_to_send, (IP_2, PORT))
data_rcv2, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
```

Thanks!

Comment: just invoke number of sends and then check for responses in the loop. there is a chance you will receive responses "out of order" and it is ok. BTW, you do not need to bind to any specific port to accomplish this.